# Explain on why the require time is not linear.

Tags: exponential-sum

Here is the question:
I got capital `X`, and I will compound interest (4%) to roll the capital, until the the interest grow > 3000.

So, I start from 6000 (X), here is my example excel:
[image]

I mark down the cell number on when it reaches more than 3,000, for 6,000, the number is row 67. Each time, I add the capital by 6,000, so, the next round, the `X` is 12,000; and the row that is bigger than 49. I do all that util the capital rach 60,000. Here is the result:

[image]

And here is the curve. 
[image]

So, my question is:
When I got 1x capital, it requires 67 times to reach my goal; 
but when I got 2x capital, it requires 49. Why it is not 30?
And I got 10x capital, it doesn't help me to get 10x faster, instead, it is only
67/8 = 8.375 faster.

Why? Thanks.

Comment: Why should it be linear?  Using the continuous compounding approximation, you are trying to solve some variant of  $e^{rt}C_0=C$  where $C_0$ is the starting capital and $C$ is the desired capital.  That gives us $t=\frac 1r\times \ln \frac C{C_0}$ which is not linear.

Comment: the interest is the gain your starting capital right? so with 6000, you reach a total of 9000 already between 12 and 13. So you then stop?

Answer (score 1):

With starting capital $C_0$ and interest rate of $r \%$ the capital after $n$ periods is $C_0(1+\frac{r}{100})^n$ so the gain on the original capital is

$$C_0\left((1+\frac{1}{100})^n -1\right)$$

which is linear in the starting capital. Your gain is $>3000\$$ after 11 periods with starting capital $6000$ (so we need  $\left((1+\frac{1}{100})^n -1\right) > \frac12$. With starting capital, say $12000\$$, we'd only need that number to be $> \frac14$ which happens much sooner, after $6$ periods. The period you solve for is in the exponent so will give a logarithmic function.